Pandoc - Markdown to PDF - Table columns overlap
I have a Markdown file with text, and tables that I would like to convert to PDF. But in one of the tables the columns overlap. How can I fix this issue?
This is a MWE with the overlapping table:
Markdown file:
|    | Vulnerability   | Level   | Metric            | Deviation                                                                                   | Description                                                                                                                                                             |
|---:|:----------------|:--------|:------------------|:--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|:------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1 | Robustness      | major   | Fail rate = 1.000 | Adding special chars `\r` in `question` can make the model to produce unexpected outputs.   | Injecting long sequences of control characters `\r` in the value of `question` can alter the model's output significantly, producing unexpected or off-topic outputs.   |
|  2 | Robustness      | major   | Fail rate = 1.000 | Adding special chars `\x08` in `question` can make the model to produce unexpected outputs. | Injecting long sequences of control characters `\x08` in the value of `question` can alter the model's output significantly, producing unexpected or off-topic outputs. |

Command used for convertion:
pandoc report_giskard.md -o demo.pdf
PDF output:

OS: Windows 10
pdflatex --version outputs:
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)
kpathsea version 6.4.0
Copyright 2024 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.43; using libpng 1.6.43
Compiled with zlib 1.3.1; using zlib 1.3.1
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04

I want the columns to not overlap.

what version of pdflatex do you have installed? (that's what pandoc is using under the hood)

I've added the version. It's: pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024)

Could you check out these links, they might help you:
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-preamble.html#latex-preamble
https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-variables.html#latex-variables

Pretty sure what's happening is that pandoc looks at the number of dashes - to determine column widths. See https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables Perhaps instead of the pipe_tables syntax you're currently using, try multiline_tables or grid_tables  

Thanks for your suggestions. The Markdown table is generated by a tool I am using, Giskard, a pentest tool, and I have no influence on the format of its output. I would like to incorporate the table into a larger file (a test report), and would prefer to find a solution, where it is not necessary to modify the table, because this process should run automatically. Is there a possibility  to pass an option to the pandoc command, to influence the creation of the table?

As @mb21 said, this is due to the relative number of hyphens - in the separator line. Here are a few ideas how to deals with this.
First, we can put all tables on separate pages in landscape mode, which allows to make the tables wider. We do that with a Lua filter:
local function latex(ltx)
  return pandoc.Blocks(pandoc.RawBlock('latex', ltx))
end

-- Make sure that the `pdflscape` package is loaded. We need it for tables.
function Meta (meta)
  local hinc = meta['header-includes'] or List{}
  hinc:insert(latex'\\usepackage{pdflscape}')
  meta['header-includes'] = hinc
  return meta
end

-- Put tables in landscape mode.
function Table(tbl)
  return latex'\\begin{landscape}' .. {tbl} .. latex'\\end{landscape}'
end

Unfortunately, this is not enough to fix this specific table, and a general fix is actually quite difficult.
For a table-specific fix, we could simply hard-code the desired column widths in the filter. Here we apply those width if the table has exactly six columns, but one could create finer-grained conditions.
function Table(tbl)
  if #tbl.colspecs == 6 then
    -- The sum of these should be 1
    local widths = {0.01, 0.11, 0.08, 0.10, 0.35, 0.35}
    tbl.colspecs = tbl.colspecs:map(function (colspec, i)
        return {colspec[1], widths[i]}
    end)
  end
  return latex'\\begin{landscape}' .. {tbl} .. latex'\\end{landscape}'
end

The output is now (somewhat) sensible looking:


Thaks for your solution, thats what I am looking for. But it seems like I miss something. When I put yout code together with my table in a markdown file, the code is just printed in the PDF. I replaced ..{tbl}.. with the markdown table.

Happy to hear. See the linked page for docs about Lua filters and how to use them. TL;DR: put the code in a new file, then pass that file to pandoc via --lua-filter. Example: pandoc --lua-filter=tablemod.lua ...

Yes, that works. Thank you.

I just adapted @tarlebs approach as follows, since I did not need the landscape mode, and it worked.
Lua file:
local function latex(ltx)
  return pandoc.Blocks(pandoc.RawBlock('latex', ltx))
end

function Table(tbl)
  if #tbl.colspecs == 6 then
    -- The sum of these should be 1
    local widths = {0.01, 0.17, 0.08, 0.14, 0.24, 0.36}
    tbl.colspecs = tbl.colspecs:map(function (colspec, i)
        return {colspec[1], widths[i]}
    end)
  end
  return latex'' .. {tbl} .. latex''
end

pandoc call: pandoc --lua-filter tablemod.lua table.md -o table.pdf
output:


This answer is based on tarleb's answer.
I wanted to keep my page portrait, but make tables wider than the page's margin.
First set the geometry of the page at the top of the markdown:
---
title: Document Title
author: Document Author
date: 14-11-2024
geometry: "left=4cm,right=4cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm"
---

And then here is the tablemod.lua:
local function latex(ltx)
  return pandoc.Blocks(pandoc.RawBlock('latex', ltx))
end

-- use the package "changepage"
function Meta (meta)
  local hinc = meta['header-includes'] or {}
  table.insert(hinc, latex'\\usepackage{changepage}')
  meta['header-includes'] = hinc
  return meta
end

-- Make tables start from further left than page margin
function Table(tbl)
  return latex'\\hspace*{-2cm}\\begin{minipage}{1.33\\textwidth}' .. {tbl} .. latex'\\end{minipage}'
end

And finally the pandoc command:
 pandoc 'my_document.md' -o 'my_document.pdf' --lua-filter=tablemod.lua

